# One source needs to compile differently on multiple machines

Tags: c++, git, makefile

I have a program in C++ that is designed to run a simulation for a summer project I'm doing. It is pretty computationally intensive, but I have gotten permission to use a cluster computer's resources to run it, but I test it and develop it on my own laptop. This program generates text files as output, and this is where I run into trouble.

I need the text files to be saved in different paths depending on whether I'm running the program on my own computer or on the cluster computer. My solution for now has been to use `$(shell hostname)` in my makefile to check which machine the code is being compiled on and, from that output, use conditional compilation with macros defined from that operation in the makefile. At one time, I was using two different versions of a header that defined macros differently on my computer versus the cluster, but I'm using a git repository to transfer changes back and forth, and I was having a very difficult time excluding one file like this.

I was just wondering what is the most preferable practice to set paths at compile time on different computers with the same source.

Comment: It doesn't sound to me like it needs to compile differently on different machines. It sounds like it needs to take some paths at run-time from either the command line, or from some sort of config file.

Comment: Oh, I never even thought about using a config file. I'll see what I can find about it. Do you happen to know how easy/hard it is to set config files up? I've thought about a command-line parameter, but the paths are quite long and share no subdirectories in common, so I'd have to type out the entire path each time... (I know, I'm too lazy, but isn't this what computers are for?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't sound to me like it needs to compile differently on different machines. It sounds like it needs to take some paths at run-time from either the command line, or from some sort of config file.

One suggestion would be to use the [boost program options library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/program_options.html) which in one simple setup allows you to read the same params either from the command line or from a config file. This is what I used when running similar jobs on a big cluster or on my laptop and it worked nicely.

Below is a simple example from their docs:

```
// Declare the supported options.
po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
desc.add_options()
    ("help", "produce help message")
    ("compression", po::value<int>(), "set compression level")
;

po::variables_map vm;
po::store(po::parse_command_line(ac, av, desc), vm);
po::notify(vm);    

if (vm.count("help")) {
    cout << desc << "\n";
    return 1;
}

if (vm.count("compression")) {
    cout << "Compression level was set to " 
 << vm["compression"].as<int>() << ".\n";
} else {
    cout << "Compression level was not set.\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've seen a lot about boost but have never tried using it. It looks like it provides a lot of important functionality in a simple way that is not provided by standard C++ headers.

Comment: @MilesYucht Boost is absolutely worth learning. It removes the constant wheel reinvention that the pre C++11 standard library requires. Once you're familiar with it you'll find yourself being waaaaay more productive.

Comment: From a brief look, it seems like it handles all sorts of command-line options, which would be great because I do use more than several command-line options already.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Alex, the easiest solution will not be at compile time, but at runtime either via a config file or command line arguments. All other things being equal, it may be easier for you to just try passing it via command line arguments using `argv` and `argc`.

Comment: The only question I have about a config file is this: I'm using a git repository with two branches. One branch (master) contains the source/other information that can be shared between the two computers, and the other contains that and the additional information to actually build and run the program (in this case, the config file). I only push master to the repo. However, I'd like to be able to do merges between these two branches while excluding this config file from master. How do I go about it? Is this a case when I want to use merge drivers?

Answer (score 1):

I am not very experienced with this, but I can think of one simple way of doing this.

Set up an environment variable that points to the appropriate directory on each machine,
and use that environment variable in your makefile.

For example,

in machine 1's ~/.bashrc

```
export MY_DIRECTORY = ~/Foo
```

in machine 2's ~/.bashrc

```
export MY_DIRECTORY = ~/Bar
```

your Makefile will use the environment variable of the machine it is running on.
Eg. $(MY_DIRECTORY)
And (~/.bashrc is not a part of your repository, so different copies can exist on the two machines)

Comment: This is a very clever idea, and it seems like it should work. It's not like my current version of the code doesn't work, but I was wondering more about what is the best practice rather than how can I simply get it to work. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

If you can stomach a dependency on QtCore (between 750K and 4MB library depending on compile options and platform), you can use QSettings to conveniently store the directory path without having to set the directory path each time. You can pass it on the command line at runtime *once* and have the program store the result into the settings file, and then that setting will become the new default for future invocations of the program without the command line argument.

Other dependency-free alternatives would involve writing your own configuration file parsing routines or using existing ones, but I always like to rely on well-tested and open source code.

Good luck!

Comment: I think that I might use this if in the future I write something that makes more use of what Qt has to offer, but for now I think I can go for reading my own config file as you, Justin, and Alex have suggested. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

You could continue with the route of using separate headers. Include both in your Git repository as `clusterHeader.h` and `laptopHeader.h` and use your existing Makefile script to build with a different header on each system. To ease linking troubles, perhaps temporarily rename or copy the file within the script from `clusterHeader.hpp` or `laptopHeader.hpp` to just plain old `header.h` while building, and change the name back at the end of the script.

If you want to keep changes in your header consistent between builds, use this method as *another* header file, and `#include` that header within your OS independent header.

i.e.

```
source.cpp
|
-> header.hpp
    |
    -> clusterHeader.hpp OR laptopHeader.hpp
```

Alternatively, as long as the systems aren't exactly the same OS (which I'm assuming they aren't since one is a cluster), you could probably quite easily get it to work with some simple `#ifdef` statements.

Finally, CMake or qmake are always options.